# Angular won't recognize components in an imported module despite export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, angular-routing

I have a module for routing and, since it needs to reference the components it will route to, I have to import those as well.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { RegisterComponent } from "./admin/register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./admin/login/login.component";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./admin/error/error.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "**", component: ErrorComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The components are placed in another module - *AdminModule*. All future components will be placed there (or in an appropriate module of their own). I wanted to replace the three imports with a single one like this.

```
// import { RegisterComponent } from "./admin/register/register.component";
// import { LoginComponent } from "./admin/login/login.component";
// import { ErrorComponent } from "./admin/error/error.component";
import { RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent } from "./admin/admin.module";
```

This doesn't work and the message says that the module *Admin* has no exported member with name *RegisterComponent* etc. So I added *exports* section to the decorator of the *AdminModule* class like this.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./error/error.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent],
  declarations: [RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Regrettably, the error message remains and I'm not sure how to make the components to be recognized as exportees of *AdminModule*. How come that neither *exports* section nor *declaration* section seems to expose them and what can I do to make it so recognizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Typescript exports with Angular exports. `@NgModule`'s exports array is designed to describe the module's public API. It does not affect how Typescript will resolve your file imports.

For this line to work like expected:

```
import { 
  RegisterComponent, 
  LoginComponent, 
  ErrorComponent 
} from "./admin/admin.module";
```

You need to export the components from the file itself.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./error/error.component";

export { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
export { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
export { ErrorComponent } from "./error/error.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent],
  declarations: [RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Read more about Typescript's `import`, `export` and `modules` in the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: So, I could omit **both** sections - *exports* as well as *declarations*?

Comment: Keep the declarations and omit the exports.